# How to convert two dates in json string to array in json?

Tags: java, json, angular, date, datepicker

i have following issue .
I send JSON like this to backend :

```
{"n":"dsad","t":"asda","term":"2021-06-26, 2021-06-30"}
```

I need to send this "term" not like this just like array ->

```
  "term": [
    "2021-07-08",
    "2021-07-06"
]
```

How can i do it?
I have angular in frontend and Java as backend.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

To acheave this you can use the split function in Jacascript and split on the , . This will give an array you can use to replace the term object.

```
object.term = object.term.replace(" ","").split(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface so you are forced to build the object in the way needed.

```
export interface InterfaceName {
 n: string;
 t: string;
 term: Date[];
}
```